# Python 3. How do you assign a variable in a function to use in the outer scope of the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables

I am extremely new to programming. I have been working on a project where the user is asked to import a number, which goes through a mathematical series. The output is then put into a function to find the factors of the number. From there I am trying to find the factors that are prime numbers? 
This is what i have so far.

```
enter code here####################################
n = int(input("Enter the n value"))
num = sum(10**x for x in range(n))
print("S",n,"is", num)
#####################################
# Factors 
#function name nfactors
def nfactors(x):
   # This function takes a number and prints the factors
  print("The factors of",x,"are:")
  for i in range(1, x + 1):
      if x % i == 0:
          print(i)

fact = nfactors(num)
print(fact)
#####################################
print('The prime numbers are:')

if fact > 1:
   # check for factors
   for i in range(2,fact):
       if (fact % i) == 0:

           break
   else:
       print(fact)
```

I know this is bad programming but I am trying to learn through doing this project. How can I then take the factors I received as the output of the function and find which factors are prime numbers. I cannot figure out how to name a variable inside the function and use that outside the function, I don't know if this is even possible. If you need any clarifications please let me know. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def nfactors(x):
# This function takes a number and prints the factors
print("The factors of",x,"are:")
for i in range(1, x + 1):
    if x % i == 0:
        print(i)
        return i 

fact = nfactors(num)
```

Use the return keyword to return the value of i or whatever it is you would like to use outside of the function!

Comment: I am a bit confused. In my case i would name var (x) before the function. Then before I send it through the for loop i would use global x. Then outside the function i would print the variable (x)?

Comment: Actually I misunderstood your question, ill update the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

> *I seriously hope that you are trying to find the factors of `n` instead of `num` as finding the factors of num for a mere number `n=12` is a great deal and it'll take several minutes or even hours even with my optimized code.*

Anyway assuming you want to find it for `n` and not `num` the below code should do your job.

In case you really want to find factors for `num`, this code will work fine for that too but it'll take too much time. Just change `factors = factors(n)` to `factors = factors(num)`.

```
from math import sqrt
#Block 1 (Correct)
n = int(input("Enter the n value"))
num = sum(10**x for x in range(n))
print("S",n,"is", num)

#---------------------------------------------------

def factors_(x):
    # This function takes a number and prints the factors
    print("The factors of",x,"are:")
    list_of_factors = []
    for i in range(1, x + 1):
        if x % i == 0:
            list_of_factors.append(i)
    return(list_of_factors) #This returns a list of factors of a given number x

factors = factors_(n) #I am assuming you want to find the prime factors of n instead of num
print(factors)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def is_prime(num): #This function returns True(1) if the number is prime else Flase(0)
    if num == 2:return 1
    if num%2 == 0:return 0
    i = 3
    while i < int(round(sqrt(num)) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:return 0
        i += 2
    return 1
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
prime_factors = []
for i in factors:
    if is_prime(i):
        prime_factors.append(i)

print("The prime factors of the numbers are:")
print(prime_factors)
```